# Object with ID '203618703567212' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

After the facebook have updated the Graph API and it's request I am facing this error

> Unsupported get request. Object with ID '203618703567212' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

I have the access token with all the valid permissions and access token is valid too,

URL is 
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/203618703567212/?fields=cover&access_token=Access Token Here
It was working previously before the Update but now it is just crashing. Any help on this will be appreciated , I have read all blogs and everything where i could ask for solution but found nothing.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52380426/6667442

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Due to the recent changes as Facebook, you are now required to request extra permissions to access user events, and in order to have access to these permissions approved you'll need to submit your app for review.

Facebook documentation here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v3.0

A good rundown of the (new) process here:
[How do I test a Facebook app since the recent introduction of login review?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177853/how-do-i-test-a-facebook-app-since-the-recent-introduction-of-login-review)

Comment: I have a previous access token with all the permissions but when I access this URL it shows this error. Secondly these are the pages event I am showing on my site, Not the User events , The public events on page are fetched and are showed up on the site.

Comment: Update: it looks like the events API is currently completely broken, Facebook is saying it's a "bug". https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/852732598261025/

Comment: Thanks a lot fot the help , I thought it's an issue on my side.

Comment: I am not using any thing other than initializing FB SDk in Application Class. Yet I am Getting this error.

Answer (score 6):

**This might be a solution for you, Just verify your AppID**

In my case ,
Again i follow this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android?sdk=maven
and found i was using wrong AppId and above link give me correct AppId by selecting my App form the dropdown.

I just changed it and it’s working.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The Id to pass into the function has to be preceded by "act_".

So replace :

```
 account = AdAccount('203618703567212')
```

with :

```
 account = AdAccount('act_203618703567212')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have face same problem. But i add the more permissions like `user_videos` and `user_posts`. Then its work.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem and my solution was that I didn't have my Pixel set up for Conversions API in the FB UI. It was configured for Browser Pixel only. Make sure your Pixel has the correct setup!

Also the FB UI graph of events has a substantial delay, but when clicking "View details" inside the events list, that data is much more up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

I was using ***`put`*** in place of ***`post`***. check your api method