# Facebook API to reply to a review on a business page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have everything set up and everything was working properly. I have a popup where the user can reply to a review on their business page. This was also working fine.

My code looks like this:

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/221454575852164769/comments";
$attachment =  array(
    "access_token"  => $page_access_token,
    "message"       => "Thank you so much!!",
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($attachment));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$comment = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$comment = json_decode($comment, TRUE);
```

This was working fine. Even now this script is working but the issue is it returns this error

```
Unsupported post request. Object with ID '221454575852164769' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation
```

Even after the Curl receives error when I go and check into the reviews on Facebook the comment was successfully posted.

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object with ID '203618703567212' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50266800/object-with-id-203618703567212-does-not-exist-cannot-be-loaded-due-to-missing)

Comment: Its already done and it is Live now. I have been using the API for last 3 months and now all of a sudden it stopped working. Also the comment is getting posted on facebook but due to some reason api is returning that error.

Comment: If so, then it looks like your ID number is wrong. In that case, you must have mis-typed a parameter with the wrong spelling - say it could be your access token or attachment - so it can't reference that instance.

Comment: The comment is successfully posted on FB. The only issue I am getting is the API is returning error instead of the new comment ID.

Comment: The error means there must be a mismatch between the comment IDs. Other than that, that's all I could conjecture on to help you.

Answer (score 0):

From the duplicate I flagged, you'll see you may need to submit your app for App Review to Facebook for permissions.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v3.0

[How do I test a Facebook app since the recent introduction of login review?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177853/how-do-i-test-a-facebook-app-since-the-recent-introduction-of-login-review)

Either that or you mis-typed a paramater/variable, hence the incorrect 18-digit ID number since it can't reference that instance of an object.